# `Between` query to mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the next data in collection:

```
{
    status: "suspended",
    number: "087495623"
    hits: 10
}
{
    status: "pending",
    number: "035672790"
    hits: 30
}
{
    status: "approved",
    number: "048750023"
    hits: 20
}
```

I want to select the records where hits > 10 and hits < 30
I'm using python to generate the query, so I do the next:

```
dict = {"hits": {"&gt": 10}}
dict.update({"hits": {"&lt": 30}})
```

so I'm trying to get the next values in dict: {"hits": {"&gt": 10}, "hits": {"&lt": 30}}
and then do:

```
db.test.find(dict)
```

I wanted to get only second row (hits> 10 and hits < 30) but I get first one as well because when I update dict with the same key it basically rewrite the previous one. 
Is there anything I can do here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do:

```
dict['hits'].update({'&lt': 30})
```

instead of your update call.

Comment: Thanks. What if I need another condition: hits = 100? So I want to select the records where hits > 10 and hits < 30 and hits = 100? What dictionary would be then? {"hits": {"$gt": 10, "$lt": 30...???}} There's no "eq" (equal) function I think

Comment: Ok I understand now that my previous comment was a kind of stupid :) thanks for your help.